# Firebase Auth: user profile changes are not synced to other devices?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Scenario:

I am logged in with Firebase Auth, using the email provider. I change my user's photoURL and displayName using this Swift code:

```swift
let changeRequest = Auth.auth().currentUser?.createProfileChangeRequest()
changeRequest?.photoURL = someURL
changeRequest?.displayName = someName
changeRequest?.commitChanges { (error) in
  // ...
}
```

From then on, when I use `Auth.auth().currentUser.photoURL` and `Auth.auth().currentUser.displayName` to render the user's name and avatar, it all works as expected. No problem at all.

However, I was also logged in on another device, before I made the changes to photoURL and displayName. And on that device, the *old* user information is shown, even when killing and restarting the app. All of that while I am using the `Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener` API as well.

Only when I logout and log back in, is the user info refreshed. I guess it's using the locally cached data, but it's not fetching the fresh user info from the server or something?

Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to force a refresh when the app starts up or something?

Edit: I've tried again a few times and yeah it's 100% reproducible.

1. Log in on two devices. Output `Auth.auth().currentUser.displayName` somewhere on screen (or to the console).
2. On device A, change the displayName. When I refresh the UI, the new name is shown. When I restart the app, the new name is shown.
3. On device B, the old name is still shown, even after killing and restarting the app. Only when I logout and back in, is the new name finally shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created a new top level Users collection, where I am now storing the user profile data. And with a snapshot listener, updating info on one device also updates it on the others. Too bad this was necessary, but it works.